# C++: Using typeid in production code

Tags: c++, typeid

Is it generally considered bad practice to use `typeid` in production code? Also, I noticed `typeid` returns `type_info`, which includes some metadata (such as a string with the type's name); is there a way to deactivate this?

Comment: You probably don't want to return `typeid` references from a library call. You'll be better off writing a function to convert a `typeid` to something else, like an `int`, where you control the mapping. Also, there's no guarantee that `typeid` will stay the same from compiler version to version. This also means you don't want to be storing `typeid` on disk, except maybe in a cache file that is not preserved between runs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to say whether the use of a particular language feature is "bad" or "good."  It really depends on how you use it.  There's nothing inherently wrong with using `typeid` if it's the right tool for the job, but if there's a better solution to whatever problem you're solving, then you should avoid using `typeid` in favor of that better solution.

It is often not a good idea to use `typeid` because its use can often be avoided by using inheritance and virtual functions.  If you can update your system in this way, then it might be a good idea to do so.

As for whether you can have `typeid` avoid returning a `std::type_info`, this shouldn't cause any performance problems.  `typeid` evaluates to a `const std::type_info&`, so it doesn't deep-copy any of the string information it contains.  Most implementations have the actual `std::type_info` object stored in the object's virtual function table, so no copying is done internally.

Answer (score 11):

1. Depends on what you're doing with the typeid. If you're using where you should use polymorphism, then of course that's bad. However, dumping out traces or things like that to debug on customers' machines is just fine.
2. The only way is to disable RTTI on your compiler. There's no standard way of doing it. Note this will also disable `dynamic_cast`.